# how to write and print some constraints in python?

Tags: python

I need to generate some constraints for an optimization problem. Its a little frustrating to make them by hand. could anybody help me to do that in python?

1-first I need to generate these 7 vectors: `V_1,V_2,...,V_7`

for `m=0 to 6` do the following:

```
V_m=(1,cos(2mpi/7),cos(2*2mpi/7),cos(2*3mpi/7),cos(2*4mpi/7),cos(2*5mpi/7),cos(2*6mpi/7))
```

Then I need the dot product of `V_m m=0,...,6` with `U=(x1,x7,x12,x16,x19,x21,x6)`.

For example for m=3:

```
A3= 1*x1+cos(2mpi/7)*x7+cos(2*2mpi/7)*x12+cos(2*3mpi/7)*x16+cos(2*4mpi/7)*x19+cos(2*5mpi/7)*x21+cos(2*6mpi/7)*x6;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic version using lists to store the variables. Hopefully it's fairly self-explanatory

```py
import math
V = []

for m in range(7): # 0,1,...6
    V_m = [1]
    for i in range(1,7): # 1,2,...,6
        V_m.append(math.cos(2*i*m*math.pi / 7))
    V.append(V_m)

U = ['x1','x7','x12','x16','x19','x21','x6']

for i in range(7):
    # zip iterates through both lists at the same time
    # a=V_m[0] b=x1, then a=V_m[1] b=x7, et c.
    print(' + '.join([str(a)+'*'+ b for a,b in zip(V[i], U)]))
```

Comment: there is a syntax error in line 8: can you see that?     V.append(V_m)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Apologies, I forgot a parenthesis on the previous line. It's fixed now. Edit: same on the final line - also fixed.

Comment: and you didn't define variables? x1,...x7

Comment: I didn't know what x1, x7 et c. should have been, so I left that for you to adapt as you need. Are they just numbers?

Comment: I just need them to be print as x1,...,x7. to use in another software

Comment: You want the values in V_m to be printed in front of x1, x7, ...? Sorry - I misinterpreted your question

Comment: sorry I forgot to put notation *. please see edit for the out put of dot product

Comment: Just made an edit to do that. The output is like this: `'1*x1 + 0.6234898018587336*x7 + -0.22252093395631434*x12 + -0.900968867902419*x16 + -0.9009688679024191*x19 + -0.2225209339563146*x21 + 0.6234898018587334*x6'`

Comment: I changed the last line so it prints instead of saving

Comment: oh wait the output is incorrect. all lines are the same!

Comment: Oops, that's fixed now.